# Help decoding Base64 using base64 -d

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

**** This post links to Windows-Based malware executables!!!   DO NOT EXECUTE DECODED SAMPLE ****

I hope I can post this here without having it pulled down.

I have 2 seemingly identical base64 encoded files.  The first I copied down manually.  The second was pulled down via a script.  I used cmp to try to find any differences.  I do not see any differences in the file... EXCEPT....

The file that I copied manually adds the base64 encoded text on over 1200 lines.
The file that was pulled down via the script adds the base64 text on only 1 line.

When I run the base64 -d command against the file I created manually, I get the decoded text into an archive file

When I run the base64 -d command against the file created by the script, I get this error:
base64: invalid input

Here is the base64 encoded text on 1 line (saved as: Note_3316_copy):
http://pastebin.com/Qs35MkS1

Here is the base64 encoded text on 1200 lines (saved as: order_id):
http://pastebin.com/H3BNcQdf

This code works on the 1200 lines of code:

```
base64 -d order_id > order_id3.zip
```

This code DOES NOT work on the 1 line of code

```
base64 -d Note_3316_copy > note.zip
```

Can anyone see why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

The 1-liner is not an actual one-liner, but contains escaped characters (a representative sample):

```
hQ0MjO4DGWN\/Czoj8IR\/LX1z8\ne+M
```

The `\` are escaped, as is the newline (`\n`). That's what's causing the error, I'd guess. Fix your script.

```
$ curl 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Qs35MkS1' -s | sed 's/\n//g;s;\\;;g' | base64 -d > blah.zip
$ curl 'http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Qs35MkS1' -s | base64 -d > blah.zip
base64: invalid input
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I've tried a variety of commands and I still can't get the base64 to decode from the single line string.
sed 's/\n//g;s;\\;;g'
sed 's/\\n//g;s/\\//g'
sed 's/\\n//g;s;\\;;g'
tr –d ‘\r\n\\’

Comment: @BeMyFriend: The first example works just fine for me. What's the exact command you used?